# gradually update date colum one day plus for each row

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1080 rows with the same date - `2018-02-26 12:31:31`

`id` column is set from `1` to `1080`.

I want gradually to update the `date` column so each next row is one day more then the previous one.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 1080; $x++) {
    $st = $db->query("update posts set date = date_add(date, interval " . $x . " day) where id =" . $x);
    $st->execute();
}
```

As final result there are date fields like `2024-02-15 ...` or `2023-05-14 ...` and the like.

What is wrong?

Comment: You want to increment the date that **is currently** on the field you are iterating over or you want to have a start date in the beginning of the loop that increments all over the fields?

Comment: i suspect some of your dates in the rows are not the same - start the script with a full wipe then try it again - update posts set date = '2018-02-26 12:31:31'

Comment: @l0ckm4, I wiped entire column twice

Comment: @man0v, each field has the same value currently. I want to increment them like `tommorrow` - `after tommorrow` - and so on,

Comment: why not 
    $st = $db->query("update posts set date = date_add('2018-02-26 12:31:31', interval " . $x . " day) where id =" . $x);  if you do not want to hard code in the start date then just grab it from a select and place it into a variable to use in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just adding the `id` (in days) to the date:

```
update posts
    set date = date + interval id day;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
To update single row

```
UPDATE posts SET `date` = DATE_ADD(`date` , INTERVAL 1 DAY) WHERE `id` = 5
```

To update all rows in post table

```
UPDATE posts SET `date` = DATE_ADD(`date` , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

PDO Connection

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 1080; $x++) {   

    $st = $db->prepare("update posts set date= date_add(date, interval " . $x . " day) where id=" . $x);
    $st->execute();
}
```

Comment: in that case all date fields will have the same value - tommorrow

Comment: Are you using PDO query?

Comment: Edited above post